# how to break the while loop if the user data is not found in the database

Tags: java, html, servlets, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to make a application in which put some data in database and from the html page i want to search the data in database. I'm  using the servlet api, i successfully retrieve the data from the database, but for the data which is not present in the database i required to get the "data not found" message on the same html page. I write the condition for checking the data for database, but for the data not present in the database i get the error message of "null pointer exception" and the while loop doesn't break by itself after checking whole data in database.

```
// this while loop doesn't terminate by itself if the data is not found in the database.

int flag=0;
while(rs.next()){
    if (rs.getString(1).equals(fname)&&(rs.getString(2).equals(lname)))
    {
        String message=rs.getString(4);
        out.print("<h2 align='center'>"+message+"</h2>");
        RequestDispatcher disp = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
        disp.include(req,res);
        flag=1;
    }
}

if(flag==0)
{
    out.print("<h1>"+"data not found"+"</h1>");
    RequestDispatcher disp = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
    disp.include(req,res);
    System.out.println(flag);        
}
}
```

Comment: Use a `break` statement?

Comment: as @Mena said, add `break;` after `System.out.println(flag);`

Comment: You don't need to break the loop; if there is no data then `rs.next()` will never be true. If the extra `}` in your code is the end of the method, you might just want to return after the first `disp.include` call, making the flag redundant. If you're getting an NPE then perhaps one of the two column values you're comparing in the loop is actually null, for one of the rows (there may be many)? Which line is the NPE reported against? (Also - why not add a filter to your query looking for the specified fname/lname, instead of getting lots of data and then checking in Java?)

Comment: Agree with @Alex, make your where clause properly, so that you could find records only with matching first_name and last_name, if no data matched, you will not be entered in while loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the value to a variable then check if is not null first:

```
String tmp = rs.getString(1);
        if (tmp != null && tmp.equals(fname) && tmp.equals(lname)) {...}
```